# input text value does not fetch data from database in php

Tags: php, sql-server

[image]

When I click on the submit button, data from the database should be displayed, but instead a empty table is displayed. I dont know what is wrong. Its working fine when I execute the SQL on the sql-server, but here it won't fetch the results and display them.

This is the expected result to be displayed.. pls can anyone help me??
[image]

```
<body>
<form id="FromID" name="FromID" method="post">
<br><br>
<div align="center" style="font-family:Rockwell,Courier Bold,sans-serif; font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">SMS Status </div>
<br><br>
<table style="border: 1px solid black" border="1" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="center" width="25%" class="style">        
        <tr>
            <td>Group Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="grp" id="grp"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subscribtion Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"></td>                
        </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td colspan ="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>       
</table>
<br>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$group=$_POST['grp'];
$subscribe=$_POST['num'];

if(!empty($group) && !empty($subscribe))
{
$q= "select send_date_d,grp_name_vc,subr_no_i,send_type_vc,result_vc,brn_id_vc,subr_mobile_vc,subr_name_vc  from tblsmsstatus
where grp_name_vc='$group' and subr_no_i='$subscribe'";
}
else
{
echo "Enter valid Group Name and Subscribtion number";  
}
$result = mysql_query($q);
  echo $q;
  echo "<table class='TFtable' border ='1' align ='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'  width='800' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='border:1px solid #0080FF;' >";
  echo "<tr><th style='background:#58ACFA;'>S.No</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Date</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Name</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Group Name</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Subscribtion Number</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Send Type</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Result</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Branch</th>
          <th style='background:#58ACFA;'>Mobile</th><tr>"; 

          $i=1;

        while($row=mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            ?>
            <tr bgcolor="#CEF6F5">
                <td align="center" style="padding-right:px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $i;?>
                </td>               
                <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">

                    <?php echo $row['send_date_d'];?>
                </td>
                <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['subr_name_vc'];?>
                </td>
                 <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['grp_name_vc'];?>
                </td>
                <td  align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['subr_no_i'];?>
                </td>
                 <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['send_type_vc'];?>
                </td>   
                 <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['result_vc'];?>
                </td>
                <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['brn_id_vc'];?>
                </td>
                <td align="center"  style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:none;">
                    <?php echo $row['subr_mobile_vc'];?>
                </td>           
            </tr>               
         <?php
          $i++;
          }            
        }
          ?>
          </table>

          </form>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Typo at `mssql_fetch_assoc` It would be `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: no am actually using mssql_fetch_assoc...means using sql server

Comment: Then `mysql_query`??

Comment: Oh My gash...I found out the mistake..i actually typed it wrong...Thanks a lot for finding out.. I had put mysql_query instead mssql_query

Comment: would you please try this one mssql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is the full code, the mistake is you havnt connected the php to the mssql server, use below code to connect first then u can run queries.

```
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS'; //your server name

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi'); //server authentication and db name

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}else{

     //all the codes goes here
}
```

Comment: ooops!!   I missed the config file..after adding it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You have used two different db library functions. You are executing query with `$result = mysql_query($q);` and in another part you are getting data from function mssql_fetch_assoc();

Use mssql_query();

Comment: Is it showing any error? try this line of code `$result = mssql_query('Your query');

if (!$query) {
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}`